Which EM/ultrasonic wavelength is suitable for seeing the possible holes inside a tree's trunk without destroying its structure?
Sometimes, wood borer insects create holes inside the trunk of a tree with a diameter of, say, less than $50 \space cm$. I want to know if there are possible ways to visualize these holes using EM/ultrasonic devices. What is the most cost-effective EM/ultrasonic wavelength for detecting these holes? Introducing relevant references that address the design of such devices is welcomed.

This might help - Review of the current state of application of wood defect recognition technology

This is readily done with ultrasound, exactly as used to image the inside of a human body. To image a defect of order ~1 centimeter in size requires a wavelength of 1/10 of a centimeter.
This testing technique is used extensively in the mechanical engineering field to locate defects inside machine parts without cutting them open. This is called nondestructive testing and analysis and entire textbooks have been written about it, including the ultrasonic defect detection technique.
